# Modifying value of structure passed to DLL from C#

Tags: c#, dll, struct, marshalling

I am trying to do 2 things: get a return value from a C dll function, and have that same function modify 1 of the members of a structure that is passed to it.  After much experimentation I was able to get the function to return a value, but I am still unable to get it to return a modified value to the C# code; the value remains (unmodified) as 0.
I've tried lots of variations (ref, [In,Out], etc) to no avail

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Vexing.Problem{
    public class myIdx : VexingObject {
        public myIdx(object _ctx) : base(_ctx) { }
        private IPlotObject plot1;
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] 
    public class PLEX { public int yowser; }

    [DllImport("my.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern int cFunction(
               [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] PLEX mPlex);

    PLEX a;
    protected override void Create() { a = new PLEX(); }
    protected override void CalcBar() {
        int mf = cFunction(a);
        plot1.Set(a.yowser); }
}}

// pertinent c dll code
typedef struct s_plex { int yowser;} cplex;

extern "C" __declspec( dllexport )  
int cFunction(cplex *Cplex){ Cplex->yowser = 44; return 1;}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `public struct PLEX` and `ref PLEX mplex`?

Comment: @JamieSee: No, that way works too :)

Comment: Or: No, both ways don't work :)

Comment: Also, if your structure is more complicated than what's shown here, you may want to look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsvc/archive/2009/02/18/marshalling-complicated-structures-using-pinvoke.aspx.

Comment: @user994179: Same result when making `a` a local variable?

Comment: @user994179: BTW, your C function does not return a value.

Comment: @leppie: Same result if I make "a" a local variable.  And I edited the C function to return a value.

Comment: @user994179: `Cplex->streamSubset` does not refer to a valid field.

Comment: @leppie: sorry, fixed that as well.

Comment: and what about int mf = cFunction(ref a);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your import declaration is wrong.
Setting the `CharSet` in your case doesn't make any sense (there are no string parameters in the native function declaration).
If you want to pass class instance, ref/out also must be thrown away (classes being passed by reference).
And the main point: `extern "C" __declspec( dllexport )` means `CallingConvention.Cdecl`.

**UPDATE**. Here's complete working code sample:
C++ (header):

```
struct CStruct
{
    int myField;
};

extern "C" __declspec( dllexport ) int MyFunction(CStruct *pStruct);
```

C++ (code):

```
int MyFunction(CStruct *pStruct)
{
    pStruct->myField = 100;
    return 1;
}
```

C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
class MyStruct
{
    public int myField;
};

class Program
{
    MyStruct myStruct = new MyStruct();

    [DllImport("MyLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static extern int MyFunction(MyStruct pStruct);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program();
        var result = MyFunction(p.myStruct);

        Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}, MyStruct.myField = {1}", result, p.myStruct.myField);
    }
}
```

Prints:

> Result: 1, MyStruct.myField = 100

Comment: One of the many incantations I tried used the "CallingConvention.Cdecl" stuff, but no go.  To confirm I just retried it: same problem.

Comment: I've updated my answer with complete working code sample. Please, check your code again (fix import definition), and then, if it still doesn't work, post it here. I don't believe in miracles.

Comment: @Dennis.Thank you.  Your code works as it should, and it shows clearly now that there is a bug in the 3rd party program I'm using.  Since I'm learning C#: why did you write: var p = new Program...  instead of just using the "myStruct" that was allocated above?  Both seem to work fine:  MyStruct p = new MyStruct();
            var result = MyFunction(p);
            Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}, MyStruct.myField = {1}", result, p.myField);

Comment: @user994179: I've tried to follow your code sample for clarity. You're passing instance field `PLEX a` to native function, so me too (`myStruct` is an instance field of `Program` class). Of course, you can't use `myStruct` in **static** method `Main` without creating any `Program` instance.

Actually, there's no difference for marshaling - local variables, instance fields or static fields being marshaled the same way.